# What mean with mqtt will qos?

Tags: mqtt

MQTT's qos about subscribe and pubulic qos mean when client receive or send message, the service qu.

But the Will QOS mean what?

I know the Will is when the client is abnormal disconnct the Will going to be send to client.

No matter the Will QoS is set to 0 / 1 / 2, it will not affect the accessibility of the connect message between the publisher and the server. The QoS of subscribers subscribing to topic is the QoS between subscribers and servers, which has nothing to do with Will QoS

Comment: https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-6-mqtt-quality-of-service-levels/

Comment: Have you taken a look at what the [mqtt spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901040) says?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/11810946/brits, I am sure I look all of MQTT3.1.1 spec, But I have this question is because of the spec not clear or not understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LastWillQoS can be set differently from message QoS.

For example, your application can use QoS=0 for message delivery, but use LastWillQoS=2 to notify subscribers if the publisher is in abnormal condition.

Please refer to [here](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-9-last-will-and-testament) for more information.

## Update 1

from your comments, I realized your actual question comes from the misunderstanding of **QoS** concept, which is basically **an agreement of both publisher and subscriber sides** (in your case, broker and subscriber) about the message delivery service quality. In principle, **both sides can ask for needed QoS**, but **the lower one** is used for actual message delivery.

In your case, broker has asked for QoS2 for delivery of will message according to your publisher's setting, but to actually deliver the will message by QoS2, your subscriber will also need to ask for QoS2, so that QoS2 agreement can be established.

Added one reference [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/8.0?topic=concepts-qualities-service-provided-by-mqtt-client#:%7E:text=The%20quality%20of%20service%20of%20a%20publication%20forwarded%20to%20a%20subscriber%20might%20be%20different%20to%20the%20quality%20of%20service%20of%20the%20publication.%20The%20lower%20of%20the%20two%20values%20is%20used%20to%20forward%20a%20publication.).

Comment: “LastWillQoS=2 to notify subscribers if the publisher is in abnormal condition”. But this Will message is already send to sever in CONNECT. Why should we sent this(Will QoS)?

Comment: The last will message will be sent by broker (not publisher), in fact, your publisher only need to set its client once during initialization. (imagine like someone tell his will to agent in case he sleep forever...the agent will keep it and execute if needed)

Comment: But as my test, if the publisher publish Will TOPIC with QoS==2, if publisher is in abnormal condition, the Will message send to subscribers from broker the QoS==the subscribers subscribe QoS, not equal with publisher publish(Will TOPIC QoS==2).

Comment: Hah...that comes to the basic principles of QoS concept. QoS is basically an agreement of both sides (in your case, broker and subscriber) about quaulity of service level, so both sides can ask for needed QoS (0,1,2), but the lower one is used for actual delivery between two sides.

Comment: Thank you for the lower one is used for actual delivery between two sides. In my test your send is very right(sorry about my English).

Comment: Can you tell me a lot. Lot of post tell me QoS==0 mean, QoS==1 mean, etc. Bue your "so both sides can ask for needed QoS (0,1,2), but the lower one is used for actual delivery between two sides" is not find. Can you give me any post discuss of this?